# c# return upcasted instance as it;s original type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dynamic

I'm trying to return upcasted instance as original type of the one.

```
public class Card : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private CardInfo cardInfo;
    public CardInfo Info { get => cardInfo; }
}

public abstract class CardConsumable : Card
{
}
    

public class CardDataBase : MonoSingleon<CardDataBase>
{
    //list will contain derived class of cards as element
    private List<Card> allCards = new List<Card>(100);
 
    public dynamic GetCard(int id)
    {
        int count = allCards.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < count;i++)
            if(allCards[i].Info.Id == id)
            {
                var card = allCards[i];
                //tried this but got error
                //var cardType = card.GetType();
                //card = card as cardType;
            }
        return null;          
    }
}
```

for example, in **GetCard()**, if element whose id is same as argument and it's original type is **CardConsumable** then i want to return it as **CardConsumable** not **Card**. in short, i want to return instance as it's original type not upcasted type

Comment: What exactly is it that you are trying to do and what is exactly going wrong? Returning the `Card` instance from within the if block should give you the instance of a type that is originally stored in the list.

Comment: What exactly would your usecase look like? Either way you will at some point have to check the type anyway .. what would it help you if the method sometimes returns `Card` and sometimes returns `CardConsumable`? -> then everything using your method would need to again check whether it is a `Card` or a `CardConsumable` in order to call certain methods on it or not ...

Comment: i guess i have misunderstood using of **dynamic** keyword . i just want to contain instances as **Card** to gather all derived classes in sole list, and then just return it as it's born type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use a generic

In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65529828/7111561) you could use a [generic method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods) and provide the desired type you are looking for and only return instances of that type using [Linq `OfType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype) like

```
// T will be whatever type you pass in
// "where T : Card" makes sure only types derived from "Card" can be used 
public T GetCard<T>(int id) where T : Card
{
   return  allCards.OfType<T>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Info.Id == id);
}
```

Of course this is not completely "dynamic" since you need to already know the type you are looking for ;)

You would call it like

```
CardConsumable cardConsumable = cardDatabase.GetCard<CardConsumable>(id);
```

which will return `null` if no card was found with the type `CardConsumable` and that `id`.

Or e.g.

```
Card card = cardDatabase.GetCard<Card>(id);
```

only needs to match the `id` but can return any type derived from `Card`.

---

#### Cast to target type on caller side

If you really want it runtime dynamic you could do kind of the same but like

```
public Card GetCard<(int id, Type type)
{
   return allCards.SingleOrDefault(x => (x.GetType().IsSubclassOf(type) || x.GetType() == type) && x.Info.Id == id);
}
```

Here you would need to cast again like

```
var possiblyDynamicType = typeof (CardConsumable);
CardConsumable cardConsumable = (CardConsumable) cardDatabase.GetCard(id, typeof(possiblyDynamicType));
```

---

#### Type-check on caller side

Or as said you would need to do the type check everytime you get a card like

```
public Card GetCard(int id) => allCards.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Info.Id == id);
```

and then do e.g.

```
var card = cardConsumable = cardDatabase.GetCard(id);

switch(card)
{
    case CardConsumable cardConsumable:
        // Do CardConsumable specific stuff
        cardConsumable.Consume();
        break;

    case SomeOtherCardType someOtherCard:
        // Do SomeOtherCardType specific stuff
        someOtherCard.SomeThing();
        break;

    default:
        // do default stuff for the rest of Card types
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You GetCard method can return a "Card" (not dynamic).

You can then use GetType() or IsAssignableFrom() on the result to get the derived type and cast it as required.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isassignablefrom?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

Since all the cards stored in the database are of type `Card`, you can write the `GetCard` method as

```cs
public Card GetCard(int id) => allCards.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Info.Id == id);
```

and then call `GetType()` on the returned card to get the concrete type.